# Rubik's cube with no squares of same color nearby

Tags: rubiks-cube

It's easy to 'scramble' a Rubik's cube so no squares of the same color are touching each other. The moves U2 D2 R2 L2 F2 B2 accomplish that.

[image: Magic cube]

A side with no squares of the same color nearby requires that the colors are not touching horizontally, vertically or diagonally. Like this:

[image]

The question is: Can you 'scramble' a cube so there are no squares with the same color nearby in all sides?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is one possibility

> U D' R2 L2 F B'

Comment: Six is indeed optimal - Brute force [Try it online](https://tinyurl.com/24ncdk54). (Sorry it is a tinyurl, the original is unfortunately too long for a comment. Alternatively adjust the code from [this codegolf.se answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/266973/53748) to have [this](https://tio.run/##pY@/DoIwEMZ3n@LGElmQxTRhMEZeQDfSmFOv0oQULGXAl68tNtrNwW@6/7/vhtm2vS63g3HuRhLUeG7RdPSYlGajRUsZX4GX7A1IvBIoDQb1nVhHmtW7/eGYxZEgJT9Ty3YTMvHtBxmyk9FQYzdSuoh6ZghVBZeFhrkP/J2nGt5OmoLzjcjj4TIksIYm9oRIffzFWTzn6QMeHVhphRe/gbFwMhM59wI) as its `is_harlequin` function.)

Answer (score 10):

The simplest way must be

> S E2 M

which looks like this:

> [image]

Now that I look at [Bennett Bernardoni's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/69908/36023), it seems to be doing exactly the same thing, except using face turns only.

Answer (score 5):

I found a super-scramble that has the following properties:

- No squares of the same color touch orthogonally or diagonally
- Each color is present on all sides 1 or 2 times
- All combinations of 4 colors are present at an intersection of 4 squares.  Possibly over the edge.

I am still missing

- No squares of the same color touch diagonally over an edge.

Here it is:
F2 L2 B2 F2 D B2 F2 D L2 U2 B F' L' F2 D U' R2 F' D U'

[image]

Note that these properties don't make the cube hard to solve.

Comment: THIS. IS. SATISFYING.

Comment: Beautiful scramble!

Answer (score 1):

We can categorize them as slice moves , and the list can be:

S E2 M

S2 E M

S E M2

S2 M E

S M2 E

S M E2,

after that all positions are just symmetry,
in fact these 6 configurutions are related in symmetry too to one another, but just to show the possibilities , I have illustrated them.